# Disable WorkManager Initializer when using app startup

Tags: android-workmanager, dagger-hilt, urbanairship.com

I'm using WorkManager 2.7.1 with Hilt and up till now I've always just removed app startup completely:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
  tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

I'm now ingesting another library that is actually using app startup so I need to just stop the WorkManager initialisation as per the guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration)

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
  android:exported="false"
  tools:node="merge">
  <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
  <meta-data
    android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
    android:value="androidx.startup"
    tools:node="remove" />
</provider>
```

Unfortunately, however, I'm not sure this is actually doing what it's supposed to. I get errors whenever I try to access a Worker in the same way that I would get in the previous configuration if I missed out the removal of `InitializationProvider`. So is the documentation correct or is it just not valid for the latest WorkManager?

I have observed that the log from WorkManagerInitializer `Initializing WorkManager with default configuration.` does not happen with either of the options but for whatever reason Hilt is no longer creating the classes referenced by @HiltWorker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, Airship has a dependency on work manager which causes it load even if you remove from app startup. Here is the [Github issue](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/issues/202).

We provided a workaround in [SDK 16.7](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/releases/tag/16.7.0):

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.urbanairship.AirshipInitializer"
                tools:node="remove" />
            
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.urbanairship.NoDependencyAirshipInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
```

Comment: Yep using this now

Comment: I am also developing SDK which use Initializer and using this solution as a workaround for apps that has custom worker initializing. The app should add this to the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I understand it now. The other Initializer that I was using (`AirshipInitializer`) is declaring a dependency on `WorkManagerInitializer` so even though I've said to `remove` it, it gets started by the `AirshipInitializer` which then stops my `Configuration.Provider` code working and thus I can't instantiate the workers!

Comment: Yeah. Same issue. Did you find any other alternative or solution to execute custom configuration while keeping the AirshipInitializer?

Comment: At the moment I've just kept with the old airship SDK, I'm going to see what this week's update looks like